# How do I reference an original command, so I can replace it with a function

Tags: bash, command, function

So I am trying to create a simple function to replace the standard `who` command with my own, similar to a function I use to replace the standard `cd` command.

**Goal:** Replace original `who` command with `who "$@" | fgrep -v <user>` in order to hide a user from it.

**Similar example:**

```
function cd () {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
```

The problem is that `who` is not a built in command like `cd`, so the above example won't work.

In case it matters, no, this isn't for malicious purposes, just learning.

Comment: The command for command is `command`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [thrig commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302320/how-do-i-reference-an-original-command-so-i-can-replace-it-in-bashrc#comment530785_302320), the command to run external commands is [`command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-command).

Your new function could look like:

```
function who() {
  command who "$@" | fgrep -v user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly call the system who:

```
function who () {
    /usr/bin/who "$@" | fgrep -v user
}
```